# How to select an Estimator (Logistic Regression) in Watson Machine Learning Studio

Tags: ibm-watson

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUbos.png)I have created a project in IBM Watson Studio. I have added the Watson Machine Learning Model to the Model but at the last step to add the model to the project is to add the Estimator like Logistic Regression but "Add" button is not displayed.I try using different browsers with no luck. I try in IE, Chrome and FireFox. 
Thank you,
Linda Jean Baptiste

Comment: Please provide a screen-shot. To be able to select an estimator you need to select a technique eg. `Binary Classification`

Comment: @chughts I have all the screenshots in a spreadsheet but I don't know how to upload a file. Please advise

Comment: We shouldn't need all your screenshots, just the one where you are expecting to see the add button, and the preceding one. You can select the image button to add them to your question.

Comment: @chughts I upload the previous and the current screenshots where I suppose to see the Add button.

Comment: You need to scroll down the list of estimators, and the Add button should be situated at the bottom right.

Answer (score 0):

Reload the page and resize your browser zoom level

### `Ctrl`+ `-`

You can use **90%** or less then again add the Estimator


This worked for me.